# sap.m.input show all suggestion and forced choose suggestion

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Expected behaviour:

1) User click on input field and the list of all values is displayed

2) Filtering starts when user enter at least 3 characters

3) User if forced to choose from suggestion (he cannot provide value which is not in the suggestion list).

So far i have following control in view:

```
this.transmitter = new sap.m.Input({
        id : this.createId("transmitterControl"),
        // placeholder : "Enter emiter ...",
        showSuggestion : true,
        suggest : oCon.handleSuggestTransmitter,
        suggestionItems:{
            path:"/services",
            template: new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"{serviceName}", key:"{serviceId}"})
        },
        startSuggestion : 3,
        suggestionItemSelected : function(evt) {
            oCon.onSuggestionTransmitterSelected(evt);
        },
    }).addStyleClass("font_bold")
```

And for the controller:

```
onSuggestionTransmitterSelected : function (e) {
        var selectedTransmitter = e.getParameter("selectedItem").getBindingContext().getObject();
        this.serviceData.transmitter = selectedTransmitter;
    },

    showAllSuggestion : function (transmiterAutoComplete) {
        console_log("showAllSuggestion");
        transmiterAutoComplete.getBinding("suggestionItems");
    },

    handleSuggestTransmitter: function(e) {
        var sTerm = e.getParameter("suggestValue");
        var aFilters = [];
        if (sTerm) {
            aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("serviceName", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sTerm));
        }
        e.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(aFilters);
    },
```

Dispaying suggestion works, when i input 3 characters an popup is shown and filtering can be done.

What i am missing:
a) displaying the whole list on click on the input field.
b) force selection (no idea whatsoever)

Ive tried setting startSuggestion : 0, but it didnt work. According to documenation it should display the popup with suggestion onClick:

> https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#getStartSuggestion
>
> getStartSuggestion(): int Gets current value of property
>   startSuggestion. Minimum length of the entered text in input before
>   suggest event is fired. The default value is 1 which means the suggest
>   event is fired after user types in input. When it's set to 0, suggest
>   event is fired when input with no text gets focus.
>
> Default value is 1.

I also tried attaching the onfocusin event. It worked, the handler is called, but i dont know what method i should call to show the suggestion popup list.

```
   transmiterAutoComplete.addEventDelegate({
            onfocusin : function(){
                console_log("testTransmiterComplete");
                app.getCurrentController().showAllSuggestion(transmiterAutoComplete);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what you this describe, [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputStates/preview) would cover most of your needs. It works however like a popup.
If that is not what you want you should continue as is. In the event delegation you will have to call "handleSuggestTransmitter". I would change it a bit so you can invoke it without actually needing the input, and it'll then return all.
Next you need a validation on the input to validate if the input is present of the list. [Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview) is an example of how to set a status on a field.

By the way, why are you using JavaScript views?

Comment: I am looking for a solution without using the popup.

Comment: Edit:
I am looking for a solution without using the popup.
I know how to get a list of suggestion (getSuggestionItems method). 
The problem is i dont know how to display these items (show the suggestion list with all items not in a popup just the same way it is shown in a 'normal use').

As for javascript view, it was just the approach used in the project before i've joined.

Comment: After all i used your solution with popup window and it works ok :)